# Как сделать вертикальное выделение текста на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, выделение-текста

Как добавить на сайт возможность вертикального выделения текста, как на картинке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня назрел интересный вопрос: Зачем?

Comment: Хочу сделать игру, где нужно находить слова в сетке из букв. Но какая разница, зачем?

Comment: А какая работа будет осуществляться с выделенным текстом? Должна быть возможность копировать?

Comment: Тогда может выделять не текст а ячейки сетки?

Comment: Я думал об этом, но не знаю, как это реализовать